# PreferenceFragmentCompat affects performance of an other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferencefragment, android-motionlayout

I followed the google guide (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) to add a PreferenceFragmentCompat to my application.

Moreover i have an other fragment (**Fragment A**), which contains a RecyclerView within a MotionLayout. The MotionLayout is used for a small animation, which expands the RecyclerView to vertical fullscreen via onSwipe.

**Now i am fancing the following issue**: After i have called the PreferenceFragment and then returned back to Fragment A, **the performance of the MotionLayout onSwipe animation is really poor/laggy**. Following the logs, the onDraw method was called multiple times when swiping.

The interesting fact is, that the onDraw method is just called once (@onCreate), when i have not started the PreferenceFragment?!

Moreover, calling an arbitrary fragment X of my other fragments doesn't affect the performance of my **Fragment A**?!

What might be a reason for this? How shall i continue my investigation?

Answer (score 5):

Answer was: the normal PreferenceFragmentCompat theme contained a vertical scrollbar attribute. My RecyclerView within Fragment A adapted that attribute which resulted in the performance drop (because of the redraws).

I fixed it with the attribute scrollbar=none.

Comment: I had a similar problem, where TextViews in my RecyclerView's ViewHolders were displaying scrollbars when the text was overflowing, after I had viewed the PreferenceFragmentCompat. The fix was to add `android:scrollbars="none"` to the TextViews.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well, thanks! But what I did was, I extended the preference style I was using `PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material`, and overridden the `android:scrollbars` attribute to be `none`, and in my `AppTheme` I set `preferenceTheme` to the style I created. This approach is probably better than adding `android:scrollbars="none"` everywhere.